# Javascript: Load an URL with JQuery ajax GET request and set headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have a small SPA with Jquery/Ajax on the frontend and Node/Express on the backend. I'm using JSON-Webtoken for the user authentication/authorization and ran into a small problem: When somebody tries to access the app endpoints **www.example.com/app/..** without a token in request header, the user gets redirected to the login page **www.example.com/app/login**. Now the problem is that after the user does log in via a post request and gets the token:

```
await $.post({
  url : 'http://localhost:3000/app/auth',
  type: "POST",
  dataType : 'html',
  data: {"email": email, "password": password},
  success : function (response) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("webtoken", response);
    // used to call  
    // window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/app";   
    // call other mysterious function?
  },
  error : function (response) {
     // log error
  }
});
```

I used to call the `window.location.href` function, however there is no way to set the received webtoken into the request header. I tried using an ajax GET request within the succes callback function of the POST request :

```
  await $.get({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("x-auth-token", response);
      },
      data: {},
      url:"http://localhost:3000/app",
      success: function(data){
        // How to actually load it?
      }
    });
```

However this loaded the html of the app into the cache, but what I need is to load the app page with previously set request headers otherwise I'll get redirected to the login page again... Is there a way to this with JQuery/Ajax from the script of another html-file or do I need to come up with a solution on the backend site?

Comment: use `location.reload();` in success function

Comment: unfortunately `location.reload` reloads the current page and doesn't provide a way to set request headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it cannt be done this way (or at least I couldn't). Instead I stored my JSON webtoken into a cookie which is sent to the user after authentication. As the cookie remains in the browser and is sent with every request, I can redirect the user to the login form with ExpressJS redirect whenever the user tries to access an app endpoint. It works like a charm now.